# vba follow hyperlink run time error

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code like this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=[someurl] 
Set mainWB = ThisWorkbook
Set inputWB = ActiveWorkbook
```

then I'm using data from inputWB (some copy paste into mainWB).

That works fine using Firefox but not always, sometimes firefox is asking me to download file from url and the result is that mainWB=inputWB, 
in result I can't use data from the target file

is there a way to wait until (or check if ) the followhyperlink method 
  load the target file from url?

Comment: If you know the name of the workbook you are downloading, (extract that from `someurl`) then set your `inputWB` equal to that specific name so you know it is correct (instead of using the notoriously unreliable `ActiveWorkbook`.)

Comment: This ' someurl '   is an url to the place that generate an excel extract. So it's not a fixed address to the excel file but a demand. 

I tried  
    
    workbooks.open(someurl) 

or this 

    set mainWB = ActiveWorkbook.followhyperlink(someurl)

both provides to errors, still only way working is the first way, but it is still unreliable ;(

Comment: `someurl` is an url to the place that generate an excel extract. So it's not a fixed address to the excel file but a demand. 

I tried  `workbooks.open(someurl)` or `set mainWB = ActiveWorkbook.followhyperlink(someurl)`

both provides to errors, still only way working is the first way, but it is still unreliable ;(

Comment: Try `If ActiveWorkbook.Path = ThisWorkbook.Path Then` do a wait command and loop back.  Maybe a Do While?  Messy but would possibly work.

Comment: Following your advisei tried the code below, still doesn't work perfect, but I have better control of execution

`myTime=now
    Do While ActiveWorkbook.Path = ThisWorkbook.Path    
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
            If CDate(Now - myTime) >= TimeValue("0:00:15") Then
                msgboxoutput = MsgBox("Connection failed")
                exit sub            
            End If
    Loop`

Answer (score 0):

Works best so far..

```
Do While ActiveWorkbook.Path = ThisWorkbook.Path
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
    If CDate(Now - myTime) >= TimeValue("0:00:15") Then
        msgbox "Connection Failed"
        exit sub
    End If
Loop
```